# Subclassing UITableViewCell only works for some StaticTableView cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a Static Tableview with multiple cells. I have created a file subclassing UITableview cell which I then go on storyboards and add is a the class for the cells.

The issue is only one of the many cells work when I go on storyboard and add it as a class?

Why is this happening?

Comment: Do you want to say "You want to use Custom Cell Class with other kind of cells without xib?"

Comment: correct! Thanks for helping out

Comment: That will work, but you will need to initialise all the components defined in the custom class manually through code, won't recommend. Rather you can easily create cell as XIB and use them instead of embedding as static, as doing so you might end up creating same static cells if you require them in other viewcontrollers. Create a cell using xib and reuse. See [this](https://medium.com/@musawiralishah/creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-nib-xib-files-in-xcode-9bee5824e722#.bg63jpqwp) for more help.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you have anything such as this is Swift?